# script to check if I can access multiple servers

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, openssh

I made this script to check if I can connect to a list of many servers:

```
for SERVER in $(cat servers.txt); do
ssh root@$SERVER && echo OK $SERVER || echo ERR $SERVER
done
```

The problem is that if is the first time I’m connecting to the server, the server asks the classic question “`The authenticity of host ‘x.x.x.x’ can't be established... bla bla bla`” Then I have to respond yes or not and it losses the purpose of making it a script, is there any way to bypass that so I can add it to the script?

Also, There are some servers in which I don't have my keys in them but they have the option to enter a password. In that case it will wait until I try a password to continue with the script execution, so I was wondering if there is a way to improve this script so if the server asks for a password then set it to ERR $SERVER and continue with the script?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ssh` without a command to execute will start an interactive login session. You need to send a command like `ssh root@$SERVER true`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you Barman, I was looking for this option as well.

Comment: Use a `while` loop to iterate over the list of servers, not a `for` loop. `while IFS= read -r SERVER; do ...; done < servers.txt`.

Comment: sshpass can be used to pass passwords. Also if possible you might want to try python and paramiko module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have quite a few servers what you may want to do is connect to all of them simultaneously. This way it only waits maximum 2 minutes (default TCP `connect` timeout) if any of the servers is unresponsive.

Connect to each server without allocating a terminal and execute `echo .` command, redirect the output into a named file. Issue these commands in a loop asynchronously. Then `wait` till all commands complete, iterate over the log files and check which ones have dots in it. Then report the servers whose log files do not have a dot in it.

E.g.:

```
#/bin/bash

servers="$@"

for server in $servers; do
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -Tn $server echo . >$server.log 2>$server.error.log &
done
wait # After 2 minutes all connection attempts timeout.
for server in $servers; do
    [[ -s $server.log ]] || echo "Failed to connect to $server" >2
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually need to establish an SSH connection?

Or is simply opening a socket connection to the host on the SSH port enough for you to determine that the server is online?

**servers.txt**

```
hostA.example.com
hostB.example.com
hostC.example.com
```

**port-probe.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT=22
TIMEOUT=3
for SERVER in $(cat servers.txt); do

    # Open a socket and send a char
    echo "-" | nc -w $TIMEOUT $SERVER $PORT &> /dev/null

    # Check exit code of NC
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

        echo "$SERVER is Available."
    else

        echo "$SERVER is Unavailable."
    fi
done
```

Comment: Matt I know that the servers are online, what I would like to do though is to know  only if my key is added to the servers or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the -o flag to set options in SSH:

```
for SERVER in $(cat servers.txt); do
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes root@$SERVER exit && echo OK $SERVER || echo ERR $SERVER
done
```

Check out the manpage for ssh_config: `man ssh_config` for all of the options available with the -o flag.

Comment: cool, I like your response, however, I'm still missing the password part :(

Comment: @VaTo use the option that disables asking for a password

Comment: You may want to consider flipping batchmode on to skip password auth: `-o BatchMode=yes` I've updated the answer to include that option. Also added `exit` to the end of the ssh command so the session exits if a successful connection was made. As @Barmar suggested in the question's comments you could use `true` as well. Just so something executes and the ssh session closes.

Comment: I did `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@$SERVER true && echo OK $SERVER || echo ERR $SERVER` and it worked. Is there any difference between those?

Comment: @VaTo I'm not sure on that one. I think Batchmode brings a few options together in one setting, but don't quote me on that.